# How can I log 500 error in PHP without php.ini

Tags: php, .htaccess

I’m trying to debug a persistant 500 error Internal Server on my website. The hosting company didn’t set up a error log system, and I can’t edit the php.ini file.

I have a ˋ`mod_rewrite.cs` rule in my .htaccess file. And when I add the `ˋ`php_flag log_errors on``ˋ I get a 500 errors on every page, instead of only the pages that are not the homepage

Comment: Perhaps PHP doesn't run as Apache module. Please check [Runtime Configuration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.php) for the complete options.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to log the errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This is the code I added to one of the PHP file that is called everywhere.